# 'function' object has no attribute 'columns'

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to encode columns as categories.

I can not work on my data frame because all columns are dtypes: object.

My code is:

categorize_column = lambda x: x.astype('category')

df.columns = df.columns.apply(categorize_column, axis=0)

I get an error:

'function' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: maybe  `df.apply(categorize_column, axis=0)`

Comment: What is `type(df)`? Maybe you accidentally assigned a function to the variable name `df`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html):

> All columns in a DataFrame can be batch converted to categorical
>   either during or after construction.
>
> This can be done during construction by specifying dtype="category" in
>   the DataFrame constructor:

So you have two options:

1. specify `dtype='category'` during the DataFrame construction `df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype='category')`
2. convert existing DataFrame columns to dtype "category" `df = df.astype('category')`

`df.columns` in your example normally return a `pandas.core.indexes.base.Index` which you can think of as a list of column headers. It does not have an `.apply` method (`pd.Series` and `pd.DataFrame` do) and it has nothing to do with the values in your DataFrame.

Also, it seems that you accidentally assigned a function to `df`. If you want to try the second method, you will need to re-create your DataFrame before you do.

Comment: @Turmacu No problem at all and welcome to SO! If you feel like I answered your question well, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. You can change your decision at any time. Later, you may gain the privilege to up/downvote questions and answers. Upvoting and accepting answers is what helps push good content to the top. [Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) normally serve a different role of asking for clarification, constructive criticism or adding a minor piece of information.